# SQL intersect with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Given these two tables/sets with different groups of items, <del>how can I find which groups in `set1` span across more than a single group in `set2`?</del> how can I find the groups in `set1` which cannot be covered by a single group in `set2`?

e.g. for tables below, `A (1,2,5)` is the only group that spans across `s1`(**1**,**2**,3) and `s2`(2,3,4,**5**). `B` and `C` are not the answers because both are covered in a single group `s2`.

I would prefer to use `SQL` (`Sql Server 2008 R2` available).

Thanks.

``````````````````````
set1                            set2
 +---------+----------+          +---------+----------+
 | group   |  item    |          | group   |  item    |
 `````````````````````+          `````````````````````+
 |   A     |    1     |          |   s1    |    1     |
 |   A     |    2     |          |   s1    |    2     |
 |   A     |    5     |          |   s1    |    3     |
 |   B     |    4     |          |   s2    |    2     |
 |   B     |    5     |          |   s2    |    3     |
 |   C     |    3     |          |   s2    |    4     |
 |   C     |    5     |          |   s2    |    5     |
 +---------+----------+          +---------+----------+
``````````````````````

Use this sqlfiddle to try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fac8a/3

Or use the script below to generate temp tables to try out the answers:

```
create table #set1 (grp varchar(5),item int)
create table #set2 (grp varchar(5),item int)

insert into #set1 select 'a',1 union select 'a',2 union select 'a',5 union select 'b',4 union select 'b',5 union select 'c',3 union select 'c',5
insert into #set2 select 's1',1 union select 's1',2 union select 's1',3 union select 's2',2 union select 's2',3 union select 's2',4 union select 's2',5

select * from #set1
select * from #set2

--drop table #set1
--drop table #set2
```

Comment: So what do yo expect as a result? A? or..

Comment: That is correct. B and C both can be satisfied by s2 alone.

Comment: Doesnt C span for s1 and s2? Because 3 is in s1 also

Comment: I understand your point. I should rephrase as "find groups of set1 which cannot be satisfied by a single group of set2". Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select groups from `set1` for which there are no groups in `set2` for which all items in `set1` exists in `set2`:

```
select s1.grp from set1 s1
where not exists(
  select * from set2 s2 where not exists(
    select item from set1 s11 
    where s11.grp = s1.grp 
    except 
    select item from set2 s22
    where s22.grp = s2.grp))
group by s1.grp
```

Comment: will give A and C I guess? but S2L wants only A ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, no it will give only A, since count(distinct set2.group) for C will be 1

Comment: No sorry, you are correct . It will give C also. OP has error in test data I guess. Because C also spans across 2 grouos in set2

Comment: Test data is correct. My question was ambiguous. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. This is ugly, but it should work. I tried it in fiddle. I think it can be done through windowing, but I have to think about it.

Here is the ugly one for now.

```
WITH d1 AS (
SELECT set1.grp
     , COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM set1
 GROUP BY set1.grp
), d2 AS (  
SELECT set1.grp grp1
     , set2.grp grp2
     , COUNT(set1.item) cnt
  FROM set1
 INNER JOIN set2
    ON set1.item = set2.item
 GROUP BY set1.grp
     , set2.grp
 )
SELECT grp
  FROM d1
EXCEPT  
SELECT d1.grp 
  FROM d1
 INNER JOIN d2
    ON d2.grp1 = d1.grp
   AND d2.cnt = d1.cnt
```

Comment: I don't think that is ugly at all.  I like it better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution through following query:

```
SELECT A.GROUP AS G1, A.ITEM AS T1, B.GROUP, B.ITEM
FROM SET1 A RIGHT JOIN SET2 B ON A.ITEM=B.ITEM
WHERE A.GROUP IS NULL
```

Comment: Didn't work. Try out using the sample tables I have added to question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Group1, a.Item, b.CNT
FROM SET1 a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT GroupA, COUNT(*) CNT
 FROM
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Group1 GroupA, b.Group1 GroupB
    FROM SET1 a
        INNER JOIN SET2 b ON a.Item = b.Item
 ) a GROUP BY GroupA
) b ON a.Group1 = b.GroupA
 WHERE b.CNT > 1
```

Comment: This returns both A and C, which is incorrect. I placed sample data in SQL to help in trying out.

Comment: c has 3,5. 3 is covered s1 and 5 is covered s2

Comment: I hope you got my point from the edits (find the groups in set1 which cannot be covered by a single group in set2)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.  I believe the following edited query will work:

```
Select distinct grp1, initialRows, max(MatchedRows) from 
  (
  select a.grp as grp1, b.grp as grp2
  , count(distinct case when b.item is not null then a.item end) as MatchedRows
  , d.InitialRows
  from set1 a
  left join set2 b
  on a.item = b.item
  left join 
    (select grp, count(distinct Item) as InitialRows from set1
     group by grp) d
  on a.grp = d.grp
  group by a.grp, b.grp, InitialRows
) c
group by grp1, InitialRows
having max(MatchedRows) < InitialRows
```

Comment: I tried fixing your query a bit, but it didn't give the correct answer. Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90511/2

Comment: Thank you @S2L!  With your edits I was able to get SqlFiddle to work and I think I have made the necessary corrections!  Always harder to do this on weekends when I don't have access to my copy of SQL server...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick. The subquery returns set2 groups per set1 group, that have a match for all the items in set1, by counting the matches and comparing the matches count to the set1 group count.

```
select s.grp from #set1 s
group by s.grp
having not exists ( 
    select s2.grp from #set2 s2 inner join #set1 s1 on s2.item = s1.item
    where s1.grp = s.grp
    group by s2.grp
    having count(s.item) = count(s2.item)   
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as Robert Co
I did not get this from his answer - came up with this independently

```
    select set1.group  
      from set1
except
    select set1count.group 
      from ( select set1.group            , count(*) as [count]  
               from set1 
           ) as set1count 
      join ( select set1.group as [group1], count(*) as [count]  
               from set1 
               join set2 
                 on set2.item = set1.item 
              group by set1.group, set2.group -- this is the magic
           ) as set1count 
        on set1count.group = set2count.[group1] -- note no set2.group match
       and set1count.count = set12count.count -- the items in set1 are in at least on set2 group
```